# WebDriver: switch between drivers

Tags: selenium, webdriver

To test a feature of the application I need to use two different drivers, because with one driver I cannot get the expected behaviour. I can switch to the second driver (driver2) like this:

```
driver2.getWindowHandle();
driver2.getWindowHandles();
```

I can work with the driver2 properly. The problem is that when trying to go back to driver1 by doing the same nothing happends! Selenium is not able to find elements. Does not work even with:

```
driver1.switchTo.window(driver1.getWindowHandle);
```

How can I solve this?

The flow of the test would be driver1, drvier2, driver1(unable to do this) and finally driver2.

Comment: Yes, but if I open a new window with the same driver I cannot get the expected result. Does Selenium support the use of more than one driver? What I need is to open different browsers for user validations.

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick test :

```
FirefoxDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver();
FirefoxDriver d2 = new FirefoxDriver();
d1.get("https://www.google.com");
d2.get("https://www.google.com");
d1.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("cheese");
d2.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("paneer");
d1.quit();
d2.quit();
```

Works for me..I do not have to use getwindowhandle for moving around the two windows of the diff drivers.  Does this address your situation?

Comment: Indeed, not needed to change focus. The problem is when trying to handle the objects with a page instantiated before using d2: page1 = PageFactory(d1, PageClass.class); --doing stuff with page1-- page2 = PageFactory(d2, AnotherPageClass.class); --stuff with page2-- page1.someMethod() crushes here! I will try to handle elements directly with d1.findElementBy..